# Analyse performance of android app using Android Development Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, performance-testing

What would be the best way to analyse performance of my app while using Android Development Studio?

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment as to why it is not a good question ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Android Studio Tips and Tricks](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html), on developer.android.com:

> ### Debugging
>
> When you build and run your app with Android Studio, you can view adb
>   and device log messages (logcat) in the DDMS pane by clicking Android
>   at the bottom of the window.
>
> If you want to debug your app with the Android Debug Monitor, you can
>   launch it by clicking Monitor in the toolbar. The Debug Monitor is
>   where you can find the **complete set of DDMS tools for profiling your
>   app**, controlling device behaviors, and more. It also includes the
>   Hierarchy Viewer tools to help optimize your layouts.

So, have you tried clicking on the monitor button? It looks like a little green android. From there you can use all the regular tools.

As for the downvote, I can only assume it was for one of two reasons. Your question starts with "What would be the best way...", which is an opinion question flag in most eyes. More likely, though, you don't show any sign that you've looked for an answer yourself. The answer is verbatim from a highly visible documentation page, and there's probably even a tooltip in AS if you check the icons in the toolbar.